# Mac apache versions

Tags: macos, mac, apache-http-server

I have installed Apache both in `/etc/apache2` as in `/opt/local/apache`.

How can I tell mac to use the `/etc/apache` and not the other one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make it so the macports apache install does not run automatically (I'm assuming macports because of the location):

```
sudo port unload apache2
```

(I'm also assuming you installed apache2.)

Now the macports apache will only run when asked. If you *never* plan to use that copy of apache, consider

```
sudo port uninstall apache2
```

and it will be gone forever (you might have to uninstall things that depend on apache as well).

Use the Sharing panel in System Preferences to turn on the preinstalled apache, or use the apachectl script as indicated by Indrek; e.g., apachectl start

Comment: thanks, but for now... I just gave up hope upon getting used to mac (kinda hate it), but when I'll have the chance and some spare time, I'll let you know the result

Comment: it did the job, I had to remove specific apache version but it did the job... thank you

Answer (score -2):

Use the `apachectl` command. For more information:

```
apachectl -h
```

In your case you need to specify an alternate configuration file with :

```
apachectl -f your_path/httpd.conf
```

Comment: this is the help flag, I would much like to have an example with what should I do

Comment: The -h give you the answer : apachectl -f your_path/httpd.conf

Comment: thank you, I had seen that... but that was just to load another `ServeConfigurationFile`, where I needed to completely remove that apache. Edit your answer to add what you just mentioned, and I'll upvote it